# How can I wait program using timer? C#

Tags: c#, timer, wait

How can I wait program using timer in C#?

example:

```
downloadImage();
waitUsingTimer(); //or we can say SLEEP
showImage();
```

Can you show me the syntax of method `waintUsingTimer()`?

Comment: What you are asking is way too broad to answer without more specifics.  How are you downloading the image? Are you multithreading? Are you using Windows Forms or WPF? etc etc

Comment: Sorry, start wait after download image. Program is only one thread and in Windows Forms.

Comment: you should look into multithreading. `downloadImage()` will block until complete by its self so the timer will be useless and redundant. I could go on.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Now, if downloadImage() is synchronous method then Why you need wait? It only makes sense if downloadImage is working Asynchronously and you want to show a progress bar during wait. Add more details to your question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Visual Studio & Windows forms this task is very easy.

You simply create a new Windows Forms Project and drag Timer from the Toolbox. You get a nice view like this.

[image]

After that you set the interval in Timer properties. 
Five seconds of delay here between tick.

[image]

And last, just double-click the timer1 and the code below to handle your logic is generated, can't get any more simple than that.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I really recommend Visual Studio Community and best of all it's free!

Download it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx